# How to retrieve sub-folder,files of a deleted folder in Trash from BOX account using V2 API?

Tags: box-api

How to get the sub-folders and files of a deleted folder in Trash using BOX API V2?. I tried using the request pattern like:

https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/{id}/trash/items.

But it doesn't work for me and it returns me only the info about the same folder.

As well as how to download the content of a deleted file?.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you must restore the item from the trash before you can access its contents (for folders) or download it (for files).